# Array/List Edit in Backend

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, query, options, sanitization

I'm kinda new to WordPress Development and even thought the question seems extremely easy for me, I haven't found any solution that works for me.

My Plugin uses a option to store a simple array of "cost centres", or in other words: array('1222', '1223', 1322', '1455'). You get the idea, just pure numbers.

This array should be editable in the backend. The user should be able to edit/delte/add such cost centres. For now I only focus on "add" since the rest is most likely the same.

I got a pretty simple code to display the cost centres:

```
    <?php
    //Grab all options
    $options = get_option($this->plugin_name.'cc');
    ?>

    <table id="costcentertable">
        <thead>
            <th>Kostenstelle</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($options as $costcenter){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $this->plugin_name.' '.$costcenter ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="btnAddd">New</button>
```

The "new" button got a simple JS attached which appends another field to write into.

Even thought it seems so simple, I have not yet figured out on how to just pass all the values so that I can use a simple "update_options(name,$newValues)".
Any clues on how to accomplish that ? I'm happy for all input, since I almost give up...

Answer (score 0):

I belive all your numbers are saved as array to your option. So `get_option($this->plugin_name.'cc')` should give you an array `$options`.

While adding get this array first, insert a new element to the array `$options[] = 'new element' ;` . Now save this array to your option again with modified $options.